# No output received when using binding parameters in WHERE statement in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

The page currently shows no output. When i say give a URL: /example.php?ID=2

I believe the problem is due to an error with using PDO as when using the SQL statement in MySQL i receive an output.

Code:

```
        <?php
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=createyo_TestDatabase;host=localhost","createyo_james","password");
$statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Edits WHERE ID = :ID AND NOT Headline = "" ORDER BY Rep DESC");
    $statement->bindValue(':ID', (int) trim($_GET['ID']), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute() or die(print_r($statement->errorInfo()));
    $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode($results);
print $json;
?>
```

Comment: Try `bindParam` instead of `bindValue`

Comment: Add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Have tried both suggestions together and individually with no output. I would like to add that even when no content from the database is outputted. I still receive "[]" due to the JSON format. However, i do not currently.

Comment: Shouldn't `"SELECT * FROM Edits WHERE ID = :ID AND NOT Headline = "" ORDER BY Rep DESC"` be either `"SELECT * FROM Edits WHERE ID = :ID AND NOT Headline = '' ORDER BY Rep DESC"` or `"SELECT * FROM Edits WHERE ID = :ID AND NOT Headline = \"\" ORDER BY Rep DESC"`?

Comment: @Sean No output after trying both suggestions. Edit: Removed other suggestions from other questions and it has worked. I was not aware that an apostrophe was needed instead of a speech mark. Thanks.

Comment: You can use either double qoutes `"` or single qoutes `'`, but if you use them inside -> `"this is an empty "" string"`/`'this is an empty '' string'` you need to either use the opposite -> `"this is an empty ''string"`/`'this is an empty "" string'` or escape them `"this is an empty \"\" string"`/`'this is an empty \'\' string'`. see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php php expects a  concatenation `.` or an end of line `;` after `"this is an empty " . " string"`